# Rename live production Database

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssis

I have database in SQL Server called 'XYZ'. Now I want to change it to 'ABC'.

The problem is that my SSRS reports and SSIS packages are connected to the XYZ.
Everything that I have build SSRS reports & SSIS is now live, users using this Reports 24/7.

Is there any way to rename database with minimum/without any server/database downtime?

Thanks

Comment: What if database name is referred in application

Comment: but my all reporting services configuration is connected with db called XYZ

Comment: Your reports should refer to a shared data source and that shared data source refers to a database. If that's the case just update the shared data source. If the database name is inside your actual reports you should do a search and replace on the RDL

Comment: Is there any good reason to change the DB name?

Comment: Thanks Nick, but this will take time.

Comment: No reason, Just F***ing requirement after one year of development

Comment: Damn. I guess finding a way to talk sense into the decision makers would be much simpler to do. Good luck.

Comment: I came across this which might help http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/9173

Comment: "Sure, we can do that. The work estimate for that is Z. I came to that by by looking at all the consumers of that database (X) and the time taken to fix one of them (Y) so X*Y. Not included in that is testing and change control. I'd like it noted that I am firmly against spending corporate dollars on this given the cost to benefit ratio and would much rather spend that on implementing feature FooBitz"

Comment: For SSIS, you *should* be able to point the connection managers to the new database with little effort via configuration. SSRS... it'll be as Nick says

Comment: Maybe a Synonym could help you here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a Rube Goldberg approach:

1. Create a new, empty database that has the name you're ultimately intending on renaming your current database to (in your example "ABC")
2. Create a synonym in your new database for every object referenced by your SSIS packages and SSRS reports that uses a three-part name as the target. For example: `create synonym [ABC].[dbo].[myTable] for [XYZ].[dbo].[myTable]`
3. Update your packages and reports to point to the new database.
4. Under cover of darkness, rename ABC to ABC_drop and XYZ to ABC.
5. Drop ABC_drop.

It doesn't eliminate downtime, but does give you time to update all of the report and ETL package references. The rollback is also simple before step 5.